# Flutter position image outside of container

Tags: image, flutter, widget, position

I'am trying to place an image a little bit outside of container on Y axis, i tried to place the image after the container then move it with transform: Matrix4.translationValues(x,Y,z) but it leaves a space on bottom of page which i don't want, basically this is what i want to acheive

this is my code

```
                        Column(
                      children: [
                        Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 151.0,
                              width: 122.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  colors: [
                                    Color(0xffFFF0E5),
                                    Color(0xffdeddc2),
                                    Color(0xffa9ceb1),
                                    Color(0xff68bdb9),
                                    Color(0xff30a6ca)
                                  ],
                                ),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color:
                                        Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 246, 250),
                                    spreadRadius: 8,
                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 6),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    child: Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 4.0,
                                            top: 9.0,
                                          ),
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                            'assets/images/Group 484.png',
                                            width: 39.52,
                                            height: 39.51,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          transform:
                                              Matrix4.translationValues(
                                                  5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                          child: IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selected = true;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            icon: CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                                  'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zrvgBfLZl94O6yJ_BlEInCIopvsokkrrrpBmVcByKwLSmacEV6B1P-SJA6eKP84ibOjFpA=s26'),
                                              child: selected == false
                                                  ? Image.asset(
                                                      'assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-heart-empty.png')
                                                  : Image.asset(
                                                      'assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-heart.png'),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Positioned(
                                      top: -20.0,
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Image.asset(
                                          'assets/images/watch-gt2-listimage-Matte-Black.png',
                                          width: 125.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Edit : i just add the full widget tree

Comment: Can you add full widget tree that will reproduce the error also we may need this image for test purpose?

Comment: done i just edited it

Comment: what about removing `Expanded` from image, instead use custom size according to Stack-Size. also you can avoid using `Matrix4` because we have `stack` here that can handle the situation.

Comment: it is better to use stack just like @YeasinSheikh said. That will also be resource friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `property`

clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,

in external widget

```
Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, // <---
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
...
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please refer OverFlowBox widget.....you will get what you want...what you have to do is in container child property you have to wrap your another container with OverFlowBox widget and have to give the width and height